# SQL EAV structure with Indexed views

Tags: sql, sql-server, indexing, entity-attribute-value, sql-view

I'm developing a general document workflow system with each document having different attributes but they share the same outline and goes through the same workflow.

So instead of creating a table for every new document type and after some research and struggle I decided to go with EAV structure for the document attributes and I'm aware of their cons but I think I have no other convenient way to achieve this, I'm I ?!!

Anyway I went with the codeplax sample of EAV structure http://eav.codeplex.com/, they crate a view per each EAV "object" in the database it can be easily queried as a normal table.

I decided to go a little further and index the view so I can gain performance and here comes the issues :

- SCHEMABINDING  : passed
- Left joins : passed
- MIN aggregate functions : couldn't pass !

Is there anyway I can Index the view or get indexed results !??

the last view query is :

```
        CREATE VIEW [dbo].[vComputer1]
    WITH SCHEMABINDING 
    AS
    SELECT       
O.ObjectID, MIN(O.Name) AS Name, 
MIN(CASE WHEN V.AttributeID = 4 THEN V.Value ELSE NULL END) AS Make, 
MIN(CASE WHEN V.AttributeID = 5 THEN V.Value ELSE NULL END) AS  Model, 
MIN(CASE WHEN V.AttributeID = 6 THEN V.Value ELSE NULL END) AS Type,  
MIN(CASE WHEN V.AttributeID = 7 THEN V.Value ELSE NULL END) AS CPU, 
MIN(CASE WHEN V.AttributeID = 8 THEN V.Value ELSE NULL END) AS Drive,  
MIN(CASE WHEN V.AttributeID = 9 THEN V.Value ELSE NULL END) AS Video, 
MIN(CONVERT(INT, CASE WHEN V.AttributeID = 10 THEN V.Value ELSE NULL END))  AS RAM,
 MIN(CASE WHEN V.AttributeID = 11 THEN V.Value ELSE NULL END) AS Optical,
 MIN(CASE WHEN V.AttributeID = 12 THEN V.Value ELSE NULL END) AS Battery,
 MIN(CASE WHEN V.AttributeID = 13 THEN V.Value ELSE NULL END) AS Screen, 
 MIN(CASE WHEN V.AttributeID = 14 THEN V.Value ELSE NULL END) AS OS,
 MIN(CASE WHEN V.AttributeID = 15 THEN V.Value ELSE NULL END) AS PurchaseDate
    FROM            dbo.Object AS O INNER JOIN
                             dbo.Value AS V ON ISNULL(V.ObjectID, 1) = O.ObjectID INNER JOIN
                             dbo.Category AS C ON ISNULL(C.CategoryID, 2) = O.CategoryID
    WHERE        (C.Name = 'Computer')
    GROUP BY O.ObjectID
```

Comment: Did you consider going with a single document table for most/all document types? Unless each document type is associated with a radically different set of attributes from all the others, this is likely to be a better solution than EAV.

Comment: yes I did, I original have a main table which contains the share attributes, but we are adding new document type every one in while so then I decided to go dynamic !

Answer (score 3):

First thing you need to do is read [Best Practices for Semantic Data Modeling for Performance and Scalability](http://sqlcat.com/sqlcat/b/whitepapers/archive/2008/09/03/best-practices-for-semantic-data-modeling-for-performance-and-scalability.aspx). There are **many** traps in the path you choose.

As for indexed views, the restrictions are documented at [Creating Indexed Views](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191432.aspx), where `MIN` and  `MAX` are very explicitly forbidden. The reason why is explained in [Why can't indexed views have a MAX() aggregate?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2134890/105929)

Comment: I see, there are many thing I could stumble with in the way, but I didn't give up yet, I'll give it a chance :)P