# Creating indexed view with using AVG in SQL

Tags: sql, aggregate-functions, indexed-view

I am trying to create an indexed view with using aggregate AVG, but can't make it work. Has anybody tried doing it? I found [this](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa933148(v=sql.80).aspx) article but couldn't figure out how to make it work. Here is my script:

```
CREATE VIEW MyView 
WITH SCHEMABINDING 
AS 
    SELECT 
        Id,  AVG(Age) as AvgAge, COUNT_BIG(*) as CountBig 
    FROM 
       dbo.Student 
    GROUP BY 
       Id;
GO

CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX MyIndex ON MyView(Id);
```

I understand `MIN` and `MAX` are not possible, but why not `AVG`?

Comment: [This previous answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2134890/1225845) should explain it - basically, because AVG (like MIN and MAX) needs to rescan all available members to recompute if a record was added, deleted, or changed.

Comment: I am not sure why my question is marked as Duplicate. Other question doesn't say anything about AVG.

Comment: "Duplicate" has a slightly broad meaning here:  the two questions have the same answer, even though the other question specifically references MAX and MIN, and your question is about AVG.  See [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/10844/302608) for a little more explanation.