# What types of aggregates can I use to create indexed view

Tags: sql, aggregate-functions, indexed-view

I have been trying to figure out what kinds of aggregates I can use to create indexed view. FYI: I was I able to create one with `SUM()`. I also found that I can't create indexed view with `MIN`, `MAX` and `AVG`. How about others? It is possible? I couldn't find any info in the web also couldn't make it work on my comp.

Answer (score 1):

According to [TechNet](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc917715.aspx), scalar aggregates are supported in indexed views.  As to why Min/Max are not supported, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2134461/why-cant-indexed-views-have-a-max-aggregate).

Answer (score 1):

[sqlmag.com](http://sqlmag.com/database-performance-tuning/indexing-dos-and-don-ts) says:

Do Index Sorting, Grouping, and Aggregating Columns

You also need to consider indexing columns that you use to order by and those that you use in a grouping expression. You might benefit from indexing the columns that the `MIN()`, `MAX()`, `COUNT()`, `SUM()`, and `AVG()` functions use to aggregate the data. When you use the `MIN()` and `MAX()` functions, SQL Server does a simple lookup for the minimum and maximum values in the column, respectively. If an index's data values are arranged in ascending order, SQL Server can read the index to quickly determine the correct values of `MIN()` or `MAX()`. The range-of-values query incorporates a filter or constraint (expressed in the `SELECT` query's `WHERE` clause or `HAVING` clause) to limit the rows that the query returns. Similarly, when you have an index, you can optimize data sorting (by using the `ORDER BY` clause) and data grouping (by using the `GROUP BY` clause), especially if the table or tables you're querying contain many rows.